# Finding latest value in the list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, max

make a list of ten integers named nums in no order. Use numbers less than 100.
use a loop to display the list with all numbers on the same line separated by spaces.
use slice syntax to make a new list named nums2 from the middle six numbers in nums.
pass nums2 as the sole argument to a void function named list_func.
inside the list_func function, display the the largest number in the slice and its index.

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

Here is the original list:

22 12 55 44 85 64 33 19 96 70

Largest value in slice is 85

85 is at index 2 in the slice

my code:

import random
    def main():

```
numbs = []
numbs2 = []
numbsList = []


for i in range(10):
    numbsList.append(random.randrange(1,100))

numbs = str(numbsList)
numbs=numbs.replace('[','')
numbs=numbs.replace(']','')
numbs=numbs.replace(',','')

print('Here is the original list: ')
print(numbs)
print('The largest value in the slice is: ')
print( 'is at index 2 in the slice.')

main()
```

I'm having trouble finding the "largest value in slice".

Comment: `largestValue = max(numbsList)`.

Comment: is it really that simple?

Comment: It's really that simple.  `max()` is a built-in function built for that purpose.

Comment: Its hard to see where you're having trouble because you don't even seem to have attempted finding the largest number or its index (and, by the way, what if the largest number occurs several times?). Also, why are you converting the list to a string and then remove the parentheses/commas? `" ".join(numbsList)` will do the same job much more nicely.

Comment: i don't quite understand the .join, and I'm removing the .replace for it?

Answer (score 3):

You can get largest value by 
    `max(numbsList)`

and the location of that value by 
    `numbsList.index(max(numbsList))`.